# Can you make nut butters without dehydrating nuts?

Tags: nuts, nut-butters

It's normally recommended to soak nuts, then dehydrate them and at some point in the future make your nut butters.

Now what if you want to bypass the dehydration process, I understand there will be more water (or whatever solution you used to soak your nuts in) however will it just make your nut butter slightly thinner rather than thicker?

Or is it not possible and all moisture should be removed regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't dehydrate the nuts, you'llend up with water and nut oil in your nut butter. This is a bad combination since it is likely to make your nut butter get mouldy very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to remove all the moisture, but you do need to remove quite a bit.

Too much moisture can actually cause a nut butter to seize up and become very thick, similar to adding water to melted chocolate.

You could roast the nuts either in the oven or in oil before grinding.  This will remove moisture much faster.

Comment: So opposed to dehydrating you can go straight from soaked and drained to roasting? Is this just a simple 20 mins in the oven to roast as normal then whack them in the blender

Comment: If you go straight from soaking,  you will probably need to roast a bit longer at a lower temperature, maybe as much as 60 minutes.  Keep an eye on the color.  Why are you soaking, by the way?

Comment: To remove the phytic acid in the nuts before processing them.